# Web API extreme high load protection

Tags: performance, web-services, security, asp.net-web-api, api-design

Let's say I have a web api which can handel 100 request/second. Once a time, there is a 10000 request/second hit into my api and crashed it. It just happend one time in a year and we don't know why it happen.

So, as a developer, when we design the API, should we consider such scenario? Should API being proctected by such peak load? If yes, which layer should do it and how?

Answer (score 1):

> So, as a developer, when we design the API, should we consider such scenario?

Yes.

> Should API being proctected by such peak load?

Yes.

> If yes, which layer should do it and how?

It is best handled by your server (IIS, for example), but you can also handle it in your service layer. The terms you want to search on are "Rate Limiting" and "Request Throttling". There are several hits on SO to start you off. If you're using IIS, you can also search on "IIS Dynamic IP Restrictions".